# ¿Hay una forma en la que no necesite seleccionar todo el código manualmente cada que quiera compilar algo c++en VScode?

Tags: c++, vscode

Estoy empezando a programar en Visual Studio Code, ya tengo extensiones para c++, code runner y el mingw, pero tengo que seleccionar todo el texto y despues darle al Run code para que compile o si no me aparece este error

[image: Este es el error que me da al intentar compilar sin seleccionar el código manualmente]

Quisiera que compilara todo el código son solo darle al botón de compilar, además de que cuando logro hacer que compile, no me aparecen los mensajes de ejecución tipo "[Running] y [Done]" aunque ya tenga activada esa función

Espero que alguien tenga la solución, muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hace mucho tiempo que no utilizo vscode. Entiendo que tu problema es que quieres compilar varios archivos a la vez. Supongo que la extencion que utilices tiene que tener alguna forma de definir como quieres compilar. De no ser el caso, busca alguna forma de integrar make o similares.

Comment: Te recomiendo que descarges un generador de proyectos (no se si se llaman así realmente), como por ejemplo CMake (tiene una extension muy util en VS Code y además es muy facil de aprender).